# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `

Tags: git, git-svn, bash

```
customfetch = !git fetch -r `wget -qO - http://hudson/url_to_project/lastStableBuild/ | gawk 'c&&!--c;/Revision:/{c=1}' | sed -ne 's/<.*//p' | sed -ne 's/\s//p'`
```

I want to create an alias for git that does a `git svn fetch -r` to the svn revision number of the last stable build reported on hudsen. I download the page, parse the revision number and try to fetch that revision number. The command that gets the revision number works ok, but when I try to create an alias it fails:

```
git svn fetch -r `wget -qO - http://hudson/url_to_project/lastStableBuild/ | gawk 'c&&!--c: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
git svn fetch -r `wget -qO - http://hudson/url_to_project/lastStableBuild/ | gawk 'c&&!--c: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with the command because I close the opened backtick and all opened `'` are closed.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are actually evaluated in a bash shell so it's better to place stuff as a single string instead to lessen the confusion:

```
customfetch = ! "git fetch -r \"$(wget -qO - http://hudson/url_to_project/lastStableBuild/ | gawk \"c&&!--c;/Revision:/{c=1}\" | sed -ne \"s/<.*//p\" | sed -ne \"s/\\s//p\")\""
```

It would still cause an error but that's already related to your arguments with `git fetch` more specifically `-r`.

Also I can't tell if `sed -ne \"s/\\s//p\"` actually has to be `sed -ne \"s/\\\\s//p\"`. Please test.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to create a function?

```
function customfetch {
    git fetch -r "$(wget -qO - http://hudson/url_to_project/lastStableBuild/ | gawk 'c&&!--c;/Revision:/{c=1}' | sed -ne 's/<.*//p' | sed -ne 's/\s//p')"
}
```

And I'm not sure what was the ! in !git for..

It's also a good to use $() over `` since it's easier to recurse, and place $() around "" to prevent unintended expansion to multiple arguments with $IFS.

Comment: None of the solutions seem to work...git cries of errors in the config file if i add them

Comment: @JasonSwartz So it's actually about git's configuration file. I thought it's about bash but it's really not about it sorry.

Comment: @JasonSwartz I added another answer. I'm going to remove this one later if I could still delete it.